# Mudar idioma da data captada no RSS

Tags: php, rss

Estou pegando o conteúdo RSS de um site com o seguinte código:

```
<?php
$rss = new DOMDocument();
$rss->load('https://jovemnerd.com.br/nerdnews/feed/');
$feed = array();
foreach ($rss->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) {
    $item = array ( 
        'title' => $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'desc' => $node->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'link' => $node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'date' => $node->getElementsByTagName('pubDate')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        );
    array_push($feed, $item);
}
$limit = 5;
for($x=0;$x<$limit;$x++) {
    $title = str_replace(' & ', ' &amp; ', $feed[$x]['title']);
    $link = $feed[$x]['link'];
    $description = $feed[$x]['desc'];
    $date = date('l F d, Y', strtotime($feed[$x]['date']));
    echo '<p><strong><a href="'.$link.'" title="'.$title.'">'.$title.'</a></strong><br />';
    echo '<small><em>'.$date.'</em></small></p>';
    echo '<p>'.$description.'</p>';
}?>
```

O que acontece, é que a data do conteúdo está e inglês, como faço para mudar para o português?
A variável que capta a data é o **$date**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olá @felipe-stoker.

Tente usar a função `strftime()` ao invés da `date()`. 
Também, antes da execução principal, adicione as funções de localidade do php para a nossa região ( `setlocale` ).

**Teu código ficaria assim**:

```
<?php

// loalidade BR e idioma pt_BR
setlocale(LC_ALL, "pt_BR", "pt_BR.iso-8859-1", "pt_BR.utf-8", "portuguese");
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');

$rss = new DOMDocument();
$rss->load('https://jovemnerd.com.br/nerdnews/feed/');
$feed = array();
foreach ($rss->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) {
    $item = array ( 
        'title' => $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'desc' => $node->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'link' => $node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'date' => $node->getElementsByTagName('pubDate')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        );
    array_push($feed, $item);
}
$limit = 5;
for($x=0;$x<$limit;$x++) {
    $title = str_replace(' & ', ' &amp; ', $feed[$x]['title']);
    $link = $feed[$x]['link'];
    $description = $feed[$x]['desc'];
    // aqui foi alterado para a função com a formatação correta
    $date = strftime("%A, %d de %B de %Y", strtotime($feed[$x]['date']));
    echo '<p><strong><a href="'.$link.'" title="'.$title.'">'.$title.'</a></strong><br />';
    echo '<small><em>'.$date.'</em></small></p>';
    echo '<p>'.$description.'</p>';
}

?>
```

Referências: http://wbruno.com.br/php/imprimir-data-atual-em-portugues-php/

[PHP: strftime - Manual](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strftime.php)

Comment: Fiz o que você disse, mas continua igual.
http://strangerthings.com.br/teste/

Comment: Felipe, aqui funcionou certinho, tando no servidor local, quanto num externo: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/79fd-931x.
Pode ser que falte alguma configuração no teu php. dá uma olhada nesta thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10909911/php-setlocale-has-no-effect

Comment: Era o servidor sim.

Answer (score 1):

Se `strtotime($feed[$x]['date'])` está ok e retornando o timestamp correto, basta trocar:

```
$date = date('l F d, Y', strtotime($feed[$x]['date']));
// Thursday November 10, 2016
```

por

```
$date = strftime('%A, %e de %B de %Y', strtotime($feed[$x]['date']));
// Quinta-feira, 10 de novembro de 2016
```

A função [`date()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.date.php) não aceita internacionalização, por isso usa-se [`strftime()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strftime.php)